# InAppWebView flutter shouldOverrideUrlLoading doesn't work when submit the form

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I am creating a flutter app, I have a page where I open the browser inside the app using InAppWebView. When navigating to other pages, I pass the header (to remove the footer in the mobile version of the site). But there is a page where the form is present. And when I click on the submit button, the page reloads, but the headers are no longer transmitted. How can I track this and transfer headers?

```
class _CreateTripScreenState extends State<CreateTripScreen> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        leading: InkWell(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
          ),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                '/home',
                ModalRoute.withName('/'));
          },
        ),
        centerTitle: false,
        title: new Text("...."),
      ),
      body: InAppWebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://..../login-app?authkey=${globals.authkey}',
        initialHeaders: {'SB-app': 'android'},
        initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
          crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
            debuggingEnabled: true,
            useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
            useShouldInterceptAjaxRequest: true,
          ),
          android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
            domStorageEnabled: true,
            databaseEnabled: true,
          ),
        ),
        onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
          webView = controller;
        },
        onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {},
        onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {},
        shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (InAppWebViewController controller, ShouldOverrideUrlLoadingRequest shouldOverrideUrlLoadingRequest) async {
          if (Platform.isAndroid || shouldOverrideUrlLoadingRequest.iosWKNavigationType == IOSWKNavigationType.LINK_ACTIVATED) {
            if (shouldOverrideUrlLoadingRequest.url.contains('/driver/') || shouldOverrideUrlLoadingRequest.url.contains('myauto') || shouldOverrideUrlLoadingRequest.url.contains('myautoform')) {
              await controller.loadUrl(url: shouldOverrideUrlLoadingRequest.url, headers: {
                'SB-app': 'android'
              });
            };
            var urll = shouldOverrideUrlLoadingRequest.url;
            var uri = Uri.parse(urll);
            if (!["http", "https", "file",
              "chrome", "data", "javascript",
              "about"].contains(uri.scheme)) {
              print(urll);
              if (await canLaunch(urll)) {
                await launch(
                  urll,
                );
                return ShouldOverrideUrlLoadingAction.CANCEL;
              }
            }
            return ShouldOverrideUrlLoadingAction.CANCEL;
          }

          return ShouldOverrideUrlLoadingAction.ALLOW;
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you notice this? According to documentation: Also, on Android this event is not called on the first page load. [useShouldOverrideUrlLoading]

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for url update with `InAppWebView.onUpdateVisitedHistory()`

```dart
Uri? previousUrl;
InAppWebViewController? webViewController;

...

InAppWebView(
  ...
  onUpdateVisitedHistory: (_, Uri uri, __) {
    // uri contains current page
    if(previousUrl != null && previousUrl != uri){
      // Reload the current page with header using URLRequest
      webViewController.loadUrl(
          urlRequest: URLRequest(url: uri, headers: {'SB-app': 'android'}));

      // Update the stored url
      previousUrl = uri;
    }
  },
  onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller){
    webViewController = controller;
  },
}
```

You can then reload the page using the InAppWebView Controller to load a URL with a header using [URLRequest](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_inappwebview/5.1.0/flutter_inappwebview/URLRequest-class.html).